# Jquery AJAX request not displaying in the required div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I seem to be having an issue with JQUERY.

I have an onclick event that calls a dialog box to open. 
On opening the dialog box it calls two functions both Jquery requests.

Both functions send out a member ID and both return the required information however only one of the requests displays in the div that it is meant to.

This is the dialog box that calls the two functions...

```
$("#memberInfo").dialog({
        open: function() {
            getUserCourseInfo(memberid); 
            getUserInfo(memberid); },
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 750,
        width: 610,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Member Information',
        buttons: {
            Close: function() {$(this).dialog( "close" );}},
        close: function() {
            document.getElementById("memberInfoInner").innerHTML="Please Wait...";}
        });
```

This is the first function...

```
function getUserInfo(str) //Show the individual user
{
document.getElementById("memberInfoInner").innerHTML="";
if (str=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("memberInfoInner").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("memberInfoInner").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
xmlhttp.open("POST","getUser.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("q="+ str);
}
```

This is the second function...

```
function getUserCourseInfo(str1)
{
document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML="";
if (str1=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhtt1p=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML=xmlhttp1.responseText;
        }
      }
xmlhttp.open("POST","getUserCourseInfo.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("q="+ str1);
}
```

The div is defined correctly later on in the code. 
Any help anyone can give would be great.

Thanks

Richard

Comment: Those functions don't use jQuery at all, they're plain old Javascript AJAX calls. What functionality are you seeing that isn't correct? Is one of the calls resulting in no output or is it outputting in the wrong place? There's a huge difference between the two. Also, post your HTML for the divs - your word that it's defined correctly really isn't enough of a guarantee.

Comment: I fail to understand you're not using jQuery's AJAX library when you're already using jQuery... It would make things much easier for you.

Comment: One other thing - which of the requests (functions) works as expected, and which is the one that's incorrect? Knowing which of them is at fault will help narrow it down, and hopefully get you an answer more quickly.

Comment: +1 to Tim's comment. Refactor this using the Ajax functions provided by jQuery (since you're already using jQuery) and your life will be greatly simplified. Some people avoid frameworks at all costs, but since you're already using it, jQuery's Ajax functions are one of the best things it has going for it.

Comment: others are correct, USE jQuery `ajax()`, but `xmlhtt1p` is just wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark, and say that this might be your problem:

```
function getUserCourseInfo(str1)
{
document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML="";
if (str1=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhtt1p=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp1.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp1.readyState==4 && xmlhttp1.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML=xmlhttp1.responseText;
        }
      }
xmlhttp.open("POST","getUserCourseInfo.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("q="+ str1);
}
```

Notice that the last three lines reference `xmlhttp` whereas the rest of the function is referencing `xmlhttp1`.

Comment: Thanks for this.

I cant believe I missed the last three lines.

Thanks again 

Rich

Answer (score 2):

USE jQuery ajax()...save yourself all this headache and extra code.

but then: 
 `xmlhtt1p`  is just wrong and other references in the second function are also incorrect.(this is your REAL issue)

Also (not really part of the question but...)
why do:

```
document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML="";
 if (str1==""){   
      document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML=""; 
      return; 
  }
```

when

```
document.getElementById("Courses").innerHTML="";
if (str1=="") {
   return;
}
```

is the same?

EDIT: Note: xmlhttp, xmlhttp1, xmlhtt1p are all global references, is that intended?  IF so, the async nature of ajax calls just might get in your way here.